# convert list to string to insert into my sql in one row in python scrapy

Tags: python, mysql

I want to convert a list object into a string and insert this string as one row in mysql database. Can someone please provide a solution to this. My code looks like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
    for site in sites:
         con = mysqldb.connect(
                    host="localhost",
                    user="dreamriks",
                    passwd="dreamriks",
                    db="scraped_data"
                 )
         cur = con.cursor()
         quest = site.select('//h2').extract()
         ans = site.select('//h3').extract()
         meta = site.select('//meta').extract()
         cur.execute("""Insert into scraped_data(h2, h3, meta) Values(%s,%s,%s)""",(quest,ans,meta))                   
         con.commit()
         con.close()
```

The code above gives the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.14.0.2841-py2.7.egg/scrapy/spider.py", line 62, in parse
        raise NotImplementedError
    exceptions.NotImplementedError:
```

Can someone help me with this error. I am stuck at this.

Comment: `insert into scraped_data(h2, h3. meta)` - is that dot a typo?

Comment: joining lists elements to a string has nothing to do with this error. Provide full traceback, looks like the parse method in the spider class is not implemented.

Comment: Same user has asked this question 4 times. Here and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079560/can-someone-tell-me-whats-wrong-with-this-script-of-mine-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9075433/error-while-inserting-into-mysql-from-python-for-loop, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9080258/problems-generating-a-list-in-python-and-storing-it-in-a-mysql-database

Comment: @Jason Sundram: Thanks, closed. Shalini, please **do not repost questions**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where your list is in the sample code, but you create a string from a list using `join`:

```
l = ['The','quick','brown','fox']
s = ''.join(l)
print(s)
```

gives:

```
Thequickbrownfox
```

Comment: You'll have to look at "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Scrapy-0.14.0.2841-py2.7.egg/scrapy/spider.py", or talk to the author.

Answer (score 2):

```
l = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
ls = ", ".join(l)
# ls == "foo, bar, baz"
```

Now you can insert this string into your database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a `list` into a `string` you can use `join`.

```
>>> myl = ['a','b','c']
>>> "".join(myl)
'abc'
```

you can use any delimiter of your choice in between the quotes

```
>>> myl = ['a','b','c']
>>> ",".join(myl)
'a,b,c'
```