# error while inserting into mysql from python for loop

Tags: python, mysql, loops, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert list to string to insert into my sql in one row in python scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061565/convert-list-to-string-to-insert-into-my-sql-in-one-row-in-python-scrapy)

Is this script correct. I want to insert the scraped out h2,h3,meta data directly into mysql database. The code below does not work correctly. Can someone please provide a solution to this. I think the problem is with the for loop.

```
    def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
         items = [site.select('//h2').extract()]
         item = [site.select('//h3').extract()]
         item1 = [site.select('//meta').extract()]
    for index,index1,index2 in range (len( items)),range(len(item)),range(len(item1)):
         con = MySQLdb.connect(
                    host="localhost",
                    user="dreamriks",
                    passwd="dreamriks",
                    db="scraped_data"
                 )
         cur = con.cursor()
         str  = items[index]
         str1 = item[index1]
         str2 = item1[index2]
         cur.execute("""Insert into heads(h2,h3,meta) Values(%s,%s,%s)""",(str,str1,str2))
         con.commit()
         con.close()
```

The error that comes is:

```
 for index,index1,index2 in range (len( items)),range(len(item)),range(len(item1)):
 exceptions.ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: And so, where you traceback print ?

Comment: I am sorry but I didnt get you dennis.

Comment: Don't keep connecting in the loop.  And as Denis asked, what errors are you getting?

Comment: The error that comes is:
    for index,index1,index2 in range (len( items)),range(len(item)),range(len(item1)):
 exceptions.ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: I've added the error in my question now.

Comment: You should also move the MySQL.connect() outside the for loop, no reason to keep re-establishing the connection, make it once and reuse for the duration of the script.

Comment: Thanks synthesizerpatel. I'll do that now. But how to check if the lists have required elements.

Comment: print item, items and item1 to check if all the lists have more than 1 value

Answer (score 2):

It seems one of your list has only one element in them, which is causing the problem.
Please check all the lists :

```
 items = [site.select('//h2').extract()]
 item = [site.select('//h3').extract()]
 item1 = [site.select('//meta').extract()]
```

Make sure they are as expected.

```
for index,index1,index2 in range (len( items)),range(len(item)),range(len(item1))
```

this syntax iterates over all the lists at once, if any of the len of lists don't match, value error will be raised,

For Better understanding of your problem see below:

```
In [1]: l1 = [1,2,3]

In [2]: l2 = [4,5,6]

In [3]: l3 = [7]

In [4]: for index,index1,index2 in range (len( l1)),range(len(l2)),range(len(l3)):
   ....:     print "Hi"
   ....:     
   ....:     
Hi
Hi
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/avasal/<ipython console> in <module>()

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

can you try this if possible:

```
for index,index1,index2 in zip(range (len( items)),range(len(item)),range(len(item1)))
```

Comment: well they all have 3 elements in them. and i thought these are arrays and not lists.

Comment: What means "are arrays not list", in python you have lists as a standard container type, not array. And you error look likes how not all lists have needed elements.

Comment: @shalini: try type(items), it shows the type as lists :)
thanks Denis.. as per my understanding also, lists required are not properly formed

Comment: ok. Whats the best way to check that all lists have needed elements

Comment: First of all you should know what to expect in lists
print item, items and item1 in the code

Answer (score 0):

Just to check - are you sure this is what you want to do?

the command

```
for x, y, z in l1, l2, l3
```

will return the first elements from each list, then the second, and so on. The better way to do this is using [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html), specifically [izip](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)

```
from itertools import izip

for x, y, z in izip(l1, l2, l3)
```

is logically equivalent, but much more efficient (izip is a [generator](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-generator))

however, it looks like what you are trying to to is index the elements of each list sequentially, so there's a lot of overhead in your code, and it breaks if the lists are of different lengths. As a first pass, I would do something logically equivalent like this. It will break on the assert for the same reason, but it should be more clear.

```
from itertools import izip
import traceback

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    # get the data however you got it (not sure exactly what the goal is here)
    sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
    items = [site.select('//h2').extract()]
    item = [site.select('//h3').extract()]
    item1 = [site.select('//meta').extract()]
    # open a connection to the server
    con = MySQLdb.connect(
               host="localhost",
               user="dreamriks",
               passwd="dreamriks",
               db="scraped_data",
          )
    cur = con.cursor()
    # run the commands:
    try:
        for st, st1, st2 in izip(items, item, item1):
             assert st and st1 and st2, 'one of the three values is missing. strings were: (%s, %s, %s)' % (st, st1, st2)
             cur.execute("Insert into heads(h2, h3, meta) Values(%s, %s, %s)" % (st, st1, st2))
        con.commit()
    except:
        #if there is a failure, print the error and die
        traceback.print_stack()
    finally:
        #no matter what happens, close the connection to the server
        con.close()
```

Comment: Thanks david. I agree with you. Can this same script be used to insert all the three lists into three different tables(one at a time).