# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'items' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variable-assignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert list to string to insert into my sql in one row in python scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061565/convert-list-to-string-to-insert-into-my-sql-in-one-row-in-python-scrapy)

I am trying to write the data extracted from HTML pages directly to a MySQL database. But the code, which used to work, no longer does. Can someone please help me out?

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
    con = MySQLdb.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="dreamriks",
        passwd="dreamriks",
        db="scraped_data"
    )
    cur = con.cursor()
    for site in sites:
        items = [site.select('//h2').extract()]
        item = [site.select('//h3').extract()]
        meta = [site.select('//meta').extract()]
    for index in range (len( items)):              #<-- exception raises here
        str = items[index]
        cur.execute("""Insert into h2_meta(h2) Values(%s)""",(str))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

The code above gives the following error:

```
exceptions.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'items' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: you need to ask better questions with more appropriate titles.  This question has practically no value to anyone else, and even if it did, how would one search for it?  Also, it's probably a good idea to censor usernames and passwords.

Answer (score 2):

Your indention is broken. Indent the block

```
for index in range (len( items)):
    str = items[index]
    cur.execute("""Insert into h2_meta(h2) Values(%s)""",(str))
```

four more spaces.

Comment: hi Tichodroma, 
I am assigning everything to the list items in the first loop and then moving each item of list to one row in mysql database. Will the approach you are suggesting be coorect for this thing?

Comment: Probably not. In this case leave the indention as is but add `items = []` above the `for site in sites` loop. Question: What do you use `item` and `meta` for?

Comment: the spider is crawling around 1000 URL's and extracting h2 and meta tags from each them in the first loop and then inserting each element of the lists items and meta into one row of mysql database. so using items and meta as lists

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have an indenting problem. The `for index in range(len(items))` is *part* of the `for site in sites` loop, right?

```
    for site in sites:
        items = [site.select('//h2').extract()]
        item = [site.select('//h3').extract()]
        meta = [site.select('//meta').extract()]
        for index in range (len( items)):             # <-- make sure this has same
             str = items[index]                       # level of indenting as previous lines
             cur.execute("""Insert into h2_meta(h2) Values(%s)""",(str))
```

Comment: I am assigning everything to the list items in the first loop and then moving each item of list to one row in mysql database. Will the approach you are suggesting be coorect for this thing?

Answer (score 0):

If `for site in sites:` doesn't iterate because `sites` is empty, then `items` never gets initialised.

When you reference it in `for index in range (len( items)):` the code is assuming that `items` has been intialised.

Comment: Please provide me some solution . I am unable to correct this code.