# Problems generating a list in python and storing it in a mysql database

Tags: python, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [convert list to string to insert into my sql in one row in python scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061565/convert-list-to-string-to-insert-into-my-sql-in-one-row-in-python-scrapy)

I have written a script to insert data into mysql as shown below, but it is inserting one item of the `items` list 344 times into the mysql database. What am I doing wrong?

```
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
    con = MySQLdb.connect(
                    host="localhost",
                    user="dreamriks",
                    passwd="dreamriks",
                    db="scraped_data"
                 )
    cur = con.cursor()
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        items = [site.select('//h2').extract()]
        item = [site.select('//h3').extract()]
        meta = [site.select('//meta').extract()]
    for index in range (len( items)):
        str = items[index]
        cur.execute("""Insert into h2_meta(h2) Values(%s)""",(str))
```

Comment: Change the title. It should say what the question is about.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are overwriting your lists instead of appending to them when you do:

```
for site in sites:
    items = [site.select('//h2').extract()]
    item = [site.select('//h3').extract()]
    meta = [site.select('//meta').extract()]
```

I think you might want to change it to:

```
for site in sites:
    items.append(site.select('//h2').extract())
    item.append(site.select('//h3').extract())
    meta.append(site.select('//meta').extract())
```

Comment: ok ralfe let me just try this

Comment: Hey ralfe. After modying according to youur suggestion, it is still printing one h2 tag into 46 rows. that meas 46 rows contain the same data scraped out of one URL. Can you please help me with this

Comment: Ok, try changing `for index in range (len(items)):` to be `for str in items:` Then remove the next line (`str = items[index]`).

Comment: i did these changes but the output remains the same. I've used 2 start_url's but this code craws the first url 46 times and writes the same to the database but doesnt write anything for next url.

Comment: Sorry, I can't be of much more help unless you can show us what the response variable's value looks like.

Comment: do you mean the output of this script? should i paste it here?

Comment: Ok, so you see in your code you have `def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)`? Well, if I can see what the value for `response` is, then perhaps the problem would be easier to solve.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
site.select('//h2').extract()
```

will return a list of all the 'h2' tags in that particular site. After appending this lists, you will need to iterate over each element in the 'items' list as they all contain a list.
The second iteration should look like this.

```
for elem in range( len( items )):
    for index in range( len(elem) ):
        str = elem[index]
        cur.execute("""Insert into h2_meta(h2) Values (%s)""",(str))
```

Also avoid using keywords like 'str' as variable names, and declare each list before appending to it.

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt work. produces errors